# How can the Internet sites showing naked "teens" be within the law?

Tags: pornography

I recall years ago a commercial for VHS videos about college girls during Spring Break showing their breasts and things of that nature. The term "behaving badly" comes to mind. In any event, a news article said that they were fined and/or cancelled because of poor record-keeping of the girls' ages. It turned out that many were underage.

Fast forward to 2017: I was puzzled when I found a site in which I simply cannot believe that those young ladies are over 18 years of age. Some look preteens.

One of such sites contains the following notice:

"Disclaimer: All models on this website are 18 years or older. TeenPort.com has a zero-tolerance policy against illegal pornography. "

My Disclaimer: That link shows pornography which can be construed as illegal. If you prefer, you don't have to visit that site. Obviously, you will be better prepared to comment if you see the images to which I am referring.

TIA

Comment: Actors in mainstream film often portray characters ten or fifteen years younger than the actor's true age, precisely because they (are presumed to) look like someone of that age. In real life there are 17-year-olds who look 40 and 25-year-olds who look 15. Pornography is no different.

Comment: I don't see the question here.  If your opinion is correct, then fraud (and various other crimes) are being committed.  If not, then they are not.

Comment: [feetwet wrote:] "I don't see the question here." If you read the title of the posting you will see it.

Comment: Mere question of fact that can't be answered here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking whether the models are over 18.

Comment: "Mere question of fact that can't be answered here."  So you are publicly showing off your ignorance. The so-called "moderators" in this site could really use some professional psychiatric help.

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic " Tim: All research -and common sense- indicates that intelligence is a complex trait. I am sure we agree on that. There is general agreement among investigators and specialists, however, that the ability to generate and comprehend relationships is a fundamental component.

Whatever you do, please don't publicize your inability to comprehend relationships.

Answer (score 5):

People aged 19 and 18 are "teens" and legally permitted to perform in pornographic videos. That's how it's legal.